# Issue while installing postgresql, pgsql in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: postgresql

I have tried to install Postgres in my ubuntu system, but facing issues from last 2 days.

Issue something related to port 5432

Error:-

> 10 main 5432 down postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/ /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlAoY.png)

Comment: No deal unless you can show an error message.

Comment: Hi Laurenz,

Thanks for the reply. Below is the image in that you can see the error which I faced
  [Error Image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlAoY.png

Comment: That's not an error message, it just says that the cluster is down. Dig into the PostgreSQL log for the error that happens when you try to start PostgreSQL.

Comment: Hi Laurenz,
We already tried to on cluster, but didn't get any success, any other source ?

Comment: As I said, look into the PostgreSQL log.